# NHibernate One-to-many relations

Tags: nhibernate, exception

Im new nhibernte and i realy close to hit my head to stones. Jokes aside; i am trying a simple one-to-many association.

I have two classes Book and Chapter. A book may contain more than one chapter. when i add assemblies to configuration it is giving a duplication error. when i remove them this time it is throwing a no persister error. I am realy stuck. Please Help....

My code and hbm files like this.

Classes:

```
public class Book
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string Author { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
    }



public class Chapter
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string Notes { get; set; }
    }
```

CODE:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ISessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
            LoadNHibernateCfg();
            using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    Book cookbook = new Book()
                    {
                        Title = "NHibernate Cookbook",
                        Author = "Jason Dentler",
                        Chapters = new List<Chapter>() { 
                        new Chapter() { Title = "Models and Mappings" },
                        new Chapter() { Title = "Configuration and Schema" },
                        new Chapter() { Title = "Sessions and Transactions" }
            }
                    };
                    session.Save(cookbook);
                    tx.Commit();
                    session.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void LoadNHibernateCfg()
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.Configure();
            cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Book).Assembly);  //____This Lines
            cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Chapter).Assembly); //____This Lines
            new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false);
        }
```

Book And Chapter hbm.xml files

```
<class name="Book" table="Books">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Title" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Author" not-null="true"/>
    <list name="Chapters" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="BookId"/>
      <index column="ChapterIndex"/>
      <one-to-many class="Chapter"/>
    </list>
  </class>



 <class name="Chapter" table="Chapters">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Title" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Notes" />
  </class>

</class>
```

And my Configuration File.

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">hqlFunction=SQLFUNC</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=BEN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=movieMng;Integrated Security=True</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are `Book` and `Chapter` in the same assembly?

Comment: how can i seperate this classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should add only one of them:

```
public static void LoadNHibernateCfg()
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.Configure();
        cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Book).Assembly);  //____This Lines
        new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false);
    }
```